# Google Chrome - Remove Class inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How do I remove a class="js-action-group" from an Iframe after it fully loads?

```
<iframe src="https://000.maps.arcgis.com/apps/dashboards/000" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0"></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the main page? If not, the main page can't access its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot alter contents of an iframe that are loaded from a different domain. This is a restriction in place by browser security. if you are on same domain you can try this**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>contents demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 

<iframe src="https://000.maps.arcgis.com/apps/dashboards/000" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0" id="frameDemo"></iframe>
 
<script>
$( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( ".js-action-group" ).remove();
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```